# Обычный активити в качестве фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity, admob

у меня возникла потребность в открытии обычного Активити как фрагмента, это принципиально важно. Я реализую один проект в котором нужно сделать один баннер admob на всё приложение, думал сделать через фрагменты, но переписывать огромные Активити в фрагменты - боль. Может есть способ заставить navhost схавать обычное Активити или может есть более рациональный метод отображения рекламного баннера на всех Активити(или поверх)?

Comment: Единственного правильного решения нет. Попробуйте создать базовую активити, в которой будет баннер и унаследуйте все остальные от неё. Открыть активити как фрагмент невозможно - можно только да, переписать целиком весь код.

Comment: Я забыл упомянуть что нельзя редактировать любой код кроме MainActivity, в котором собственно и нужно инициализировать баннер.. вот такой геморрой

Comment: Если вам можно редактировать только MainActivity, а баннер надо добавить в другую активити, то задача нерешаема. (Технически решаема рисованием поверх вообще всего интерфейса девайса, но это лютый костыль, требующий опасного разрешения и помимо редактирования манифеста может привести к бану в магазине.)